# How can I increase Poison Burst damage?

Tags: torchlight-2

The description of Poison Burst says, it inflicts x% of weapon DPS as poison damage. So, how do I increase the damage? By investing into strength or focus or both?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both strength and focus affect skills whose damage is based on "%WDPS as element", no matter what the damage type of the weapon you use is.  The skill computes its weapon DPS by pretending your weapon is poison type, regardless of what damage type it actually deals.

Comment: Sounds plausible, but how do you know? Do you have a source or done some experiments?

Comment: Take a look [here](http://forums.runicgames.com/viewtopic.php?f=30&t=44975)